# How to find points with an vertical slope

Tags: analysis

I have the following problem:

The function $y(x)$ is implicit defined as $$x^3 - 3xy + y^3 - 1 = 0$$.
The function consists of "3 branches". And there two are two points where `y' = inf`, meaning the slope does not exists (is infinite).

How can I find the coordinates of these two points (where the function branches are stitched together)?

[image]

Comment: Well, maybe you can try to find the (implicit) derivative?

Comment: The slope is infnite if ```y' = inf <=> dx/dy = 0```, which would be ```(y^2-x)/(y-x^2) = 0```, but how do I get from there the two points?

Comment: From what you wrote, at these points $x=y^2$; replace in the expression and ... observe ! There is something nice now.

Comment: Claude indeed has a point. You first get the conditon $x=y^2$, so plug that into the original equation and you'll get an expression only in terms of $y$. Not an easy expression to solve, but nevertheless ...

Comment: Ah, then i get ```y^6 - 2y^3 - 1 = 0``` and then i can use this solution to calculate x. Thank you very much.

Comment: That gives $(y^3-1)^2=2, y^3=1\pm \sqrt 2$